# Classify data in a List

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have a List here:

```
List<String> container = new ArrayList<String>();
container.add("Book");
container.add("Paper");
container.add("Book");
container.add("Pen");
container.add("Pen");
container.add("Book");
```

How can i classify data in this List into a 3 sub-list like this:

```
List <String> container1  ==>that still keep 3 elements which have the same name "Book"
List <String> container2  ==>that have 1 element which is "Paper"
List <String> container3  ==>that still keep 2 elements which have the same name "Pen"
```

Thank you for your help

**In the case of there are many comment that my question are unclear**, so i will ask like this

If i have a list with more duplicated elements than the example list above, the sub-container list like container1,container2..., containerN will generate depend on the number of duplicated elements

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Create three lists and copy the original list's references to the new lists based on string comparisons?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind the verbosity, then you can use Google Guava's [`FluentIterable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html).  This will allow you to, given a particular [`Predicate`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html), filter a collection.

```
List<String> words = Lists
        .newArrayList("Book", "Paper", "Book", "Pen", "Paper", "Book");

FluentIterable<String> bookFiltered = FluentIterable
        .from(words)
        .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(final String input) {
        return "Book".equals(input);
    }
});

FluentIterable<String> paperFiltered = FluentIterable
        .from(words)
        .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(final String input) {
        return "Paper".equals(input);
    }
});

FluentIterable<String> penFiltered = FluentIterable
        .from(words)
        .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(final String input) {
        return "Pen".equals(input);
    }
});

System.out.println(bookFiltered); // [Book, Book, Book]
System.out.println(paperFiltered); // [Paper, Paper]
System.out.println(penFiltered); // [Pen]
```

Comment: thanks but what if i have N duplicated elements in that list, how can i do?

Comment: It will still give you all duplicated elements in the list.  There's no removal of any duplicates from this operation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic [working implementation](http://ideone.com/YlRdxQ) that will do what you want for any number of duplicated elements, as well as collections of any type that correctly overrides `hashCode` and `equals` (e.g., Integer, String, Double):

```
public <T> Collection<List<T>> classify(Collection<T> container) {
    Map<T, List<T>> lists = new HashMap<>();
    for (T element : container) {
        List<T> elementList = lists.get(element);
        if (elementList == null) {
            elementList = new ArrayList<>();
            lists.put(element, elementList);
        }
        elementList.add(element);
    } 
    return lists.values();
 }
```

Sample usage:

```
Collection<List<String>> lists = classify(container);
System.out.println(lists);
```

Comment: Nick, I'm glad to be of service. If you feel like Makoto answer or mine were right, please accept one of our answers.